# How can I add a "select" column to a Silverlight DataGrid w/MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, checkbox

I need to have a column with checkboxes in my DataGrid for the user to select various rows (that an operation would be performed on later).  The grids ItemsSource is bound to an ObservableCollection.  My quickest solution (not the best, but just to get it working) I thought would be to inherit from the class in the collection, adding in an IsSelected property I could bind to and just work from there.  However, the collection I'm starting with is already instantiated, and downcasting/contravariance isn't working for me.  And, it wouldn't be feasible to recreate a collection of the derived class.

So, I'm looking now for a simple solution with maybe an attached behavior on a checkbox column.  I'm trying not to spend too much time on this, so I need some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually had to do it this way:

1) Use a CheckBox inside a TemplateColumn instead of the DataGridCheckBoxColumn because the DataGridCheckBoxColumn doesn't have Checked & Unchechecked events to hook into.

2) Create a behavior class for the Checked and Unchecked events on the checkbox, with seperate commands for each; I had to create a behavior class because while the CheckBox has a Command property already, there didn't seem to be any way of determing the checked/unchecked status of the control, unless used as a CommandParameter, which I needed to pass information for the DataGrid bound item in.

3) Pass in a reference to the VM from the View, and declare the VM as a static resource in code behind; I had to do it this way in order to bind to the commands in my VM with the checkbox, while having access to the same Observab

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're doing is a good way to do it. The subclass you're using is kind of a "ViewModel" for the original class.

However, there is another way that I found in [this post by Laurent Bugnion](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/05/19/handling-datagrid.selecteditems-in-an-mvvm-friendly-manner.aspx) that uses the `SelectedItems` collection of the `DataGrid` control, which you can't bind to directly, unfortunately, because it's not a `DependencyProperty`, but he uses the `EventToCommand` behavior from his [**MVVMLight Toolkit**](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) and passes the `SelectedItems` collection as a `CommandParameter`.

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that SelectedItems works independently of a column "selector" like a checkbox. It's like I'm maintaining my own "SelectedItems" collection, regardless of what is selected in the grid.  A row could be selected, but the checkbox unchecked.

Comment: I guess this could also be achieved with something like Behaviors, but I'm not used to them.

Comment: A more generalized approach using an extended DataGrid absolutely would be the way to go, but I just need to worry about this one instance right now instead of guessing at how much I'd need to extend it to be useful elsewhere.

Comment: Well, you can extend it as much as you need for just this situation, and maybe if you need it later, add more features ;)